# cast on object of type superclass returns object of type subclass in java

Tags: java, binding, casting, subclass, superclass

I have implemented the following code in order to understand the difference between static and dynamic binding:

```
class A {

    int met(A a) {
        return 0;
    }

    int met(B b) {
        return 1;
    }

    int met(C c) {
        return 2;
    }
}

class B extends A {

    int met(A a) {
        return 3;
    }

    int met(B b) {
        return 4;
    }

    int met(C c) {
        return 5;
    }
}

class C extends B {

    int f() {
        return ((A)this).met((A)this);
    }
}

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        C x = new C();
        System.out.println(x.f());
    }
}
```

The result I get is 3, but I don't understand why, since the first cast is made to A.

Comment: Is not there a better time of the year to start learning Java ?

Comment: Why not? What do you expect to happen? `B` overrides that function.

Comment: There is no such thing as bad time to start learning Java :))

Comment: Well yes, it overrides it, but the cast is made to A, not to B. Is the answer the fact that it goes bottom-up on the line of inheritance? In other words, when I make a cast to the superclass A, it takes the last child of A?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is two questions for the price of one.  (1) Why do we get the implementation from class B, and (2) why do we get the version of the method with the parameter of type A.

For question (1), the thing to remember is that the class of an object doesn't change when you cast it, or assign it to a variable whose type is something different.  So in  your example, the class of `this` is always `C`, because that's what you created.  Class `C` inherits its version of `met(A a)` from class `B` because it doesn't have its own version, and because class `B` has overridden the version in class `A`.  This is what polymorphism is all about - the version of the method depends on the *class* of the object that you call it on, not on the *type* of the expression that you use to call it.

For question (2), it's a wee quirk of Java that method signatures are evaluated at compile time.  So the compiler sees that  you're passing an expression of *type* `A` into your method, so it chooses the signature `met(A a)`.  Because this decision is made at compile time, the actual class of the argument doesn't make any difference - the compiler has already chosen the method, based on the type of the expression.  In other words, Java *doesn't* give you polymorphism of method parameters.

Answer (score 6):

So, let's look at the call:

```
((A)this).met((A)this);
```

That's equivalent to:

```
A target = this;
A argument = this;
target.met(argument);
```

So, for the last line, the compiler looks up the *signature* based on the compile-time types involved - it will look in `A` (and superclasses) for a method called `met` which has a parameter that is compatible with `A` (the compile-time type of the argument). Overload resolution finds that the answer is:

```
int met(A a)
```

That's determined the *signature* at compile-time. However, the *implementation* of that method is determined at execution time, based on the execution-time target of the method call. That type is `C` here - because `this` is a reference to an instance of `C`. (The `f` method is called on an instance of `C`.)

Now `C` doesn't override `int met(A a)`, but `B` (its superclass) does - so that's the implementation that's used. It doesn't matter that `B` *also* overrides `met(B b)` and `met(C c)` because the compiler has already determined that it's the `met(A a)` method which is being called.